# Probability of a player winning a snooker tournament

Tags: probability

Two players have a snooker tournament, the first player to win 6 frames wins the match. (Best of 11)

Assume that the probability of player A winning each frame is P, regardless of who starts. If A does not win then his opponent does. (No Draws)

If P = 0.4 what is the probability that A wins the tournament?

This one stumped me, so any help from you math experts would be really appreciated!

Comment: What are the possible events that lead to a victory for $A$? What are their associated probabilities?

Comment: A possible event that leads to a victory for $A$ is $AAAAAA$ with which I mean $A$ won the first $6$ game in a row, other events are $AABAAAA$ with which I mean, $A$ won the first $2$ games, then $B$ won a game, then $A$ won $4$ games. Can you list all of those events? What are the associated probabilities of these events happening? If the answer to one of both questions is no, please let me know.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong here but there should be 30 ways in which A can win 6 times. Using permutations  P(6,2) = 30 ?

Comment: @Ordered we should be using combinations, not permutations.  Furthermore, it is out of the total 11 possible games, 6 of those being wins.  There are thus $\binom{11}{6} = 462$ ways of winning exactly six out of 11 games.

Comment: The events of interest are the events corresponding to the final scores $6-0$, $6-1$, $6-2$, $6-3$, $6-4$, $6-5$ with on the left the final score of player $A$ and on the right the final score of player $B$.

The probability that $6-0$ happens, can only happen in one way. Player $A$ wins all games. The probability of that happening is $0.4^6$

Comment: The probability that $6-1$ happens, can happen in multiple way. Player $B$ could have won the first game, the second game, the third game, the fourth game, the fifth game or the sixth game, and player $A$ won in all those cases the other game. The probability of one of those singleton events happening is $0.4^6 * 0.6$ but since the event $6-1$ consists of $6$ singleton events, the probability of $6-1$ happening is $6 * 0.4^6 * 0.6$

Comment: The probability that $6-2$ happens, can happen in multiple way. Each of these single ways have a probability of $0.4^6 * 0.5^2$. There are how many multiple ways in which this can happen? etc. (for $6-3$ you will get a certain number $ * 0.4^6 * 0.6^3$, for $6-4$ you will get a certain number $ * 0.4^6 * 0.6^4$ and finally $6-5$ will give you a certain number  $ * 0.4^6 * 0.6^5$ ).

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  You can assume they in fact play all $11$ games.  A has to win at least $6$ of them. You have a binomial distribution.  Can you compute the chance that A wins exactly $6$ of $11$?  Now just add the chances of $7, 8, 9, 10, 11$